# Path integral for boson vs fermion (soft derivation + use )

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, fermions, bosons

I have been looking around for a soft derivation with a bit of detail for boson and fermion path integrals that I could understand. I have a passing knowledge generally of what a path integral is in Quantum mechanics but I don't understand any of the derivations that I have come across for boson and fermion path integrals.
 It would be nice if perhaps a very simple example of each in use is demonstrated with some explanation. Is there a scenario where a mixture of the two is used?

Comment: Did you see the Peskin Schroeder one? He does the Boson path integral in details

Comment: Actually, I don't have that book, but  I found a quantum statistical mechanics introduction here http://statphys12.inln.cnrs.fr/IMG/pdf/Muramatsu.pdf , and can't quite make sense of it even at this level.